# How to do a bitwise comparison of a unicode string?

Tags: sqlite, unicode

I'm trying to store a unicode string in SQLite, and then select by that same string, like this:

```
> sqlite3 .\cache.db
SQLite version 3.38.5 2022-05-06 15:25:27
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t (v TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO t VALUES("いろ");
sqlite> INSERT INTO t VALUES("ろい");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t WHERE v = "いろ";
??
??
```

Why does the select return both entries in this example?

The strings have to be exactly the same, bit by bit. If there is different casing, or different code points to represent the same characters, they should be considered different strings.

Comment: As long as the program handling the database uses the same encoding, you should not see any duplicates or mixups.  In your case, `いろ`  vs `ろい` are as different as `ABC` and `CBA`.  First value is stored in UTF8 as `e38184e3828d`, the last value as `e3828de38184`

Comment: That's what I would expect too, but why does the select return both strings?

Comment: It works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=82683ed833c32bd342292b636cc0cc5b

Comment: I notice the output is replacement characters.  Is it possible that the console or database is unable to process the Unicode and in fact all 3 strings are identical?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but I'm getting the same result if I do it programmatically with C++ : /

Comment: So if you query the database with C++, what does it tell you are the contents of each row?

Comment: Running the above commands in the Windows command prompt, then using Python (with its Unicode support) to insert the same values and query, the command line values are literal question marks, while the values inserted via Python are correct.

Comment: I have Chinese IME support installed.  If I change the command line to Chinese `chcp 936` and insert some Chinese characters it work.  `sqlite3.exe` seems to support the current code page only and is not a Unicode-aware app.  It writes the data encoded in the current code page.  If I switch back to default `chcp 437` and read the data I get mojibake (cp936 characters decoded as cp437).

Comment: You can use the `hex()` function to get the raw bytes of the value and see if they're what you think they should be.

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried to setup a minimal C++ example and it does work after all. I guess the problem is something else. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing in C++ and it actually already works:

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db = nullptr;
    
    int rc = sqlite3_open("C:/Users/slysherz/Desktop/test.db", &db);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE t (v TEXT);", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO t VALUES(?);", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "いろ", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    
    rc = sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "ろい", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM t WHERE v = ?", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "いろ", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        std::cout << sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0) << std::endl;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    rc = sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `πüäπéì`, but that's a fight for another day.

It seems the problem has nothing to due with comparison, but with the way the console and the sqlite3.exe handle unicode characters.

If I open the database the C++ program generates:

```
sqlite> select hex(v) from t;
E38184E3828D
E3828DE38184
```

Whereas for the other one:

```
sqlite> select hex(v) from t;
3F3F
3F3F
```